# laravel 9 seeder with json field multi-language

Tags: laravel

my seedr:

```
public function run()
{
    ClientPermission::create([
        'id' => 1,
        'section_ar' => 'المريض',
        'options_ar' => [
            'patients_tree'   => 'قوائم المريض',
        ],
    ]);
}
```

i get it in mysql like this:
{"patients_tree":""\u0642\u0648\u0627\u0626\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u064a\u0636""}

in my model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'options_ar' => 'json',
    'options_en' => 'json',
];
```

i tried already:

```
json_encode('قوائم المريض', JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

but i get the same result
what should i do more guys?
thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i found it guys:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts
the solution to make your owns casts instead of laraveldefault